# Can't set side padding/margin to ViewPager container layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm tryintg to implement [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) calendar in my app with few modifications. There is custom ViewPager there:

```
    <com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
            android:id="@+id/months_infinite_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>
```

Pager is located under one parent layout. What I wanted was to position the pager inside it's parent using margin or padding. It appears that setting side (left, right) margin or padding makes the app loop somewhere inside ViewPager `onMeasure()` method.

Can't find any information, that ViewPager can't have a parent with side margin/padding set. `onMeasure()` contains now only super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) and It seems that it loops in native libraries for some reason. That doesn't happen without margin/padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the container layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_page"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Just a layout taking half of the screen, so what? It seems the problem was `android:layout_width="1dp"`. Change to `android:layout_width="200dp"` helped. it doesn't matter if it's 200, 100 or any other number. I think the ViewPager was positioning itself on 1dp first, and then recalculated from percentage width, but just guessing